# Bundler + Rails3.1: installing gems from github repository using bundler and load paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I have a Gem that I need to install it from github using bundler I added it to my Gemfile

```
gem 'attr_encrypted', :git => "git://github.com/danpal/attr_encrypted.git"
```

Bundle installed it:

```
$bundle show attr_encrypted
/Users/dani/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@railsrc/bundler/gems/attr_encrypted-05bbe677eae6
```

The problem is that rubygems won't see it:

> Because Rubygems lacks the ability to handle gems from git, any gems
>   installed from a git repository will not show up in gem list. They
>   will, however, be available after running `Bundler.setup`.

Now if I run bundler/setup it does work:

```
DANIELs-MacBook-Air-2:authy-SSO dani$ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > require 'attr_encrypted'
LoadError: no such file to load -- attr_encrypted
    from /Users/dani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/dani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/dani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > require 'bundler/setup'
 => true
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :003 > require 'attr_encrypted'
 => true
```

The question is, where do I add this load paths to rails3.1 so that all gems I get from Bundler are automatically in the load path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 3 apps automatically load bundler on startup an thus makes all the gems available to Rails' load path. The neccessary code to load bundler is automatically generated in your `config/boot.rb` file. You can start the rails console using `rails console` and will see that `attr_encrypted` is already loaded.

If you need a different process with an adapted loadpath (e.g. a simple ruby script an irb session, or a rake task) you can start it with `bundle exec` which will adapt the load path for the process and then start it. You can use it like `bundle exec irb`.

You should **always** use `bundle exec` to start scripts with bundler present as only that way you ensure that the correct gems and versions are used and all dependencies are available. For more information, please refer to the [bundle exec man page](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html) or generally the [bundler website](http://gembundler.com).